# How do I know when the first confirmation happened on blockchain with web3?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I want to listen to when first confirmation happened on blockchain with web3, can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Every transaction is a promise so you can use ".then" and console.log

```
await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    .then(console.log)
```